# How can i make my iframe app visible for everyone?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm new to Facebook app development and I ran into a stupid issue:

I made a simple app consisting of a flash player embedded in an iframe stored on my server and then I added it (as a tab) to a Facebook Event page I also created.

My problem is that the iframe will only load the page's content if the user's role is mapped in the app settings; it works fine for me since I'm the administrator and I believe my test users can also see it quite well, but for everyone else the iframe is blank.

Any ideas on how to make it visible for everyone?
Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

- Content page is here:
  http://livextend.com/facebook/nosajthing_musicbox/
- Tab is here:
  http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nosaj-Thing-no-Musicbox/174470872628888?sk=app_214393448619749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your app is in `Sandbox Mode`. If it is, you're right - only Admin, Devs, and Testers will be able to use / see the app. If you want everyone to see it, disable `Sandbox Mode`:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Select your app and then `Edit Settings`
3. `Settings` > `Advanced`
4. In `Authentication` section, set `Sandbox Mode` to `Disabled`

Comment: Nop, Sandbox Mode is disabled. I just added more info on the issue though.

Comment: Okay. Yeah the player loads for me, but I get this on both the stand alone site and the FB Page: "Timed-out trying to establish a connection to the server", so it shouldn't be an issue on the FB end. You don't get this error?

Comment: Hmmm now that's interesting because it's supposed to time-out. The issue was that I could not see the iframe itself (nothing was loaded). That means it's not role related!

Comment: So far the behavior seems erratic, I'm wondering if its got anything to do with my ISP (we changed our DNS settings 8h ago)...

Comment: I'll give it another try Monday; i'll update the situation then, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah that might be it. Good luck!